# I don't understand the output of this program

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code in assembly, when entering and integer like "131071" the output is 1 and -1. I'm trying to understand why, I understand that it is separating the integer in half but why do I get this result ?

```
        .text
       .globl main
   main:                   #main has to be a global label
       addu  $s7, $0, $ra  #save the return address in a global register

   loop:
     # Read in the word to split
       .data
       .globl  message1
   message1:  .asciiz   "\nEnter an integer value: " #string to print
       .text
       li  $v0, 4          # print_str
       la  $a0, message1   # takes the address of string as an argument
       syscall

       li  $v0, 5          # read_int
       syscall
       beqz  $v0, exit1    # terminate on 0 value

       add  $a0, $v0, $0   # move $v0 to $a0
       jal  halves         # call the function halves
       add  $s0, $v0, $0   # save first return value
       add  $s1, $v1, $0   # save second return value

     # Now print out halves
       .data
       .globl  message2
   message2:  .asciiz   "\nThe halves are: " #string to print
       .text
       li  $v0, 4         # print_str
       la  $a0, message2   # takes the address of string as an argument
       syscall

       li  $v0, 1          # print_int
       add  $a0, $0, $s0   # put value to print in $a0
       syscall

       .data
       .globl  message3
   message3:  .asciiz " and "    # string to print
       .text
       li  $v0, 4    # print_str
       la  $a0, message3   # takes the address of string as an argument
       syscall

       li  $v0, 1          # print_int
       add  $a0, $0, $s1   # put value to print in $a0
       syscall
       j  loop             # get another word

   exit1:
       .data
       .globl  message4
   message4:  .asciiz   "\nProgram terminated. " #string to print
       .text
       li  $v0, 4          # print_str
       la  $a0, message4   # takes the address of string as an argument
       syscall

             # Usual stuff at the end of the main
       addu  $ra, $0, $s7  # restore the return address
       jr  $ra             # return to the main program
       add  $0, $0, $0     # nop

     # subroutine halves

       .globl  halves
   halves:
       sub  $sp, $sp, 8    # make space on the stack for two items
       sw  $s1, 4($sp)     # save register $s1       
       sw  $s0, 0($sp)     # save register $s0
       add  $s0, $a0, $0   # register $s0 contains the word to split
       sra  $v0, $s0, 16   # extract the upper half
       add  $s1, $0, 0xffff      # create a mask
       and  $s1, $s1, $s0  # extract the lower half
       sll  $s1, $s1, 16   # ensure sign extention
       sra  $v1, $s1, 16   # return to position
       lw  $s0, 0($sp)     # restore register $s0
       lw  $s1, 4($sp)     # restore register $s1
       add  $sp, $sp, 8    # adjust the stack before the return 
       jr  $ra             # return to the calling program
```

No errors, I just don't understand the output. If i use a number like 2000 for example the result is 0 and 2000

Comment: Which part is unclear? It's just printing `x / 65536` and `x % 65536`. The `-1` is really `65535` but sign extended.

Comment: `halves` is very inefficiently written!  You could just use `$t0` and `$t1` instead of saving/restoring `$s0..1`.  And `0xFFFF` is encodeable as an immediate for `and` (16-bit zero-extended) but ironically *not* for `add` (16-bit sign-extended).  And if you're going to shift left/right anyway, you might as well just do that to knock off the high bits without bothering to AND at all.  So the function could just be 4 instructions (3 shifts and `jr $ra`).